# Creating Apex Test methods in Salesforce "constructor not defined"

Tags: java, salesforce, apex-code

I've written an apex class that executes when a user presses a button. It saves the current data to the log, checks the page that they are currently on and reloads it (so they are displayed with a blank instance of the logger). I am currently trying to write the test method for this class and am getting this error: "Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [Logger_Extend].() at line 45 column 38" (line 45 is this one "Logger_Extend controller = new Logger_Extend();").

Here is the relevant code. Does anybody have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Logger_Extend {

private final RCA_Logger__c Log;

public Logger_Extend (ApexPages.StandardController
                            stdController) {
   Log = (RCA_Logger__c)stdController.getRecord();
}

 public PageReference XX() {

// Add the account to the database.   
insert Log; 

// Send the user back to current page.  

  PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
  pageRef.setRedirect(true);
  return pageRef;
}

static testMethod void myTest() {

      Logger_Extend controller = new Logger_Extend();
      PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
      System.assert(controller.XX() == pageRef);

   }
```

}

Answer (score 5):

You don't have a constructor for **Logger_Extend** that does not take any arguments, but you are trying to instantiate one in your test.

While an argument-less constructor is created for you by default, once you *add* a custom constructor that takes arguments, you need to also add an argument-less constructor.

From the [Apex Developers reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_constructors.htm?SearchType=Stem):

> If you write a constructor that takes arguments, you can then use that constructor to create an object using those arguments.
>
> If you create a constructor that takes arguments, and you still want to use a no-argument constructor, you must include one in your code. Once you create a constructor for a class, you no longer have access to the default, no-argument public constructor. You must create your own.